How to configure multiple db using EntityManager - JPA?
Hi I've trying to connect 2 database using entity manager in MySQL database. Also, I've connect multiple database using hibernate but I'm unable to connect 2 or more database using EntityManager or @PersistenceContext(unitName = "foo") private EntityManager configTmp;
Here is my code of xml file. Please have a look and suggest me where to modify the code.
<bean name="configds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${configUrl}" />
        <property name="username" value="${configName}" />
        <property name="password" value="${configPass}" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" name="configFac">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="configds" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
      
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.visa.entities</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

        <bean name="configTemp" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="configFac" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="configTxn" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="configFac" />
    </bean>

<!--__________________________________________ DB for visa_slovakia ______________________________________________-->

<bean name="svkds" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${svkUrl}" />
        <property name="username" value="${svkName}" />
        <property name="password" value="${svkPass}" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" name="svkFac">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="svkds" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
      
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.visa.entities</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="svkTemp" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="svkFac" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="svkTxn" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="svkFac" />
    </bean>


And this is my Dao code
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "configTemp")
private EntityManager configTmp;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "svkTemp")
private EntityManager svkTmp;

And the error is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'configTemp' is expected to be of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate'
Also, I know I'm using hibernate template instead of entity manager but frankly I don't know what to write in that place. I've been looking for solution on internet but not finding the exact solution.
Thank You

Use the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory instead of HibernateSessionFactory in yuor XML, ditch the template, replace the transaction manager with the JpaTransactionManager.

Can you help me with sample code. It would be great help.
